# How do I fix HandleToggleState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple material-ui toggle in my react component. I want to use it to toggle state (false/true). If I start with useState(false) the first time I click the toggle it says false rather than true.

I'm wondering if another react hook would solve for this. useEffect, useCallback...

```
const Component = () => {
  const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(false);

  const handleToggleChange = () => {
    setToggleValue(!toggleValue);
    console.log("toggle value in handle: " + toggleValue);
  };


  return(
    <FormControlLabel
       control={
          <Switch
             checked={toggleValue}
             onChange={handleToggleChange}
             value="my toggle"
          />
       }
    />
  );
};
```

I would expect `setPreseason(!preseason);` to set the state opposite of what it currently is. True to false and false to true.

It probably is but when I log the state on the next line it logs the initial state and will always log the opposite of what the toggle is.

Comment: That's because the state updater is asynchronous

Comment: How can I fix it? Will the useEffect or useCallback hook work? If so what would the code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `state updater function` returned by [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) is asynchronous

If you need to react to `state` changes [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) is the place for it

```
const Component = () => {
  const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(false);

  const handleToggleValue = () => {
    setToggleValue(!toggleValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("toggleValue: " + toggleValue);
      // second argument to useEffect is an array of dependencies
      // this function is going to run every time one of the dependencies
      // changes
  }, [toggleValue])

  return (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Switch
          checked={toggleValue}
          onChange={handleToggleValue}
          value="my toggle"
        />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I've seen examples like this online before and don't understand how it fits into my current code. Where does the setToggleValue get set and how does this work with the handleToggleValue?

Comment: @sbaden updated my answer to your component, in `handleToggleValue` you just update the `state` and inside `useEffect` you provide a function to run every time `toggleValue` changes

Comment: I changed my code to reflect what you have above and I get the same result. How is useEffect changing anything?

Comment: @sbaden How is it the same ? [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-paper-te3j2) it first logs `false` when the component mounts and then logs the opposite on every `state` change

Comment: I updated your sandbox to add an additional console log to demonstrate what I mean.   https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-heyrovsky-4kq9e

Comment: I think I left out an important detail... I'm trying to do something with the new toggleValue after I setToggleValue inside the handleToggleValue. Would I instead put that functionality inside the useEffect?

Comment: @sbaden Yes, every time you need to do something when the `state` changes put it inside `useEffect` and don't forget to add the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The issue is about which value `toggleValue` is inside the closure. Is not what you expect. Instead pass a callback to `setToggleValue`. You will get the current state back, that you can then change.

```
const handleToggleValue = () => {
  setToggleValue((toggleValue) => !toggleValue);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It still logs the initial value

Comment: you put that console log statement outside the callback, and inside the render function, have you? can you share more code?

Comment: I don't currently have a callback and don't know how to format it. I tried to simplify the code I was sharing but can give you more - How should I share it with you?

Comment: add it in your original question; code as it is should work fine, the error is elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly, except that `toggleValue` is just a local variable and is not changed just by calling `setToggleValue` (the state will be changed, but that happens asynchronously).

You could do something like this instead:

```js
const handleToggleValue = () => {
  const newToggleValue = !toggleValue;
  setToggleValue(newToggleValue);
  console.log('toggleValue: ' + newToggleValue);
}
```

It depends what your intention is with the new toggle value. This simply fixes what you were doing with the console.log call. But you may run into further trouble after that, given that you are using the new toggle value before the state is updated. But that is for another SO question...

Comment: This didn't work for me. It still logs the initial value.

Comment: You are probable better off using the useEffect example; but here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/brombal/pen/GRKZgdV) to show how this works (not sure what you were doing differently, but the console logs the current checkbox state when you toggle it).